Inverse Fourier transform of $\sqrt{i \omega \mu_0/\sigma}$
I am dealing with a physics problem in which the frequency domain impedance of a metal is given by $Z_s(\omega)= \sqrt{i \omega \mu_0/\sigma}$. Here $\omega$ is the angular frequency, $\mu_0$ is the vacuum permeability, and $\sigma$ is the conductivity of the metal. Does $Z_s(\omega)$ has a real inverse Fourier trasform? In other words does the function $\sqrt{i\omega}$ has a real inverse Fourier transform?

Welcome to Math StackExchange. Since this is your first question on this site, I recommend you read about how to ask a good question and update yours accordingly. Your question is currently unclear - What is the context? What do these notations mean? Most importantly, you must show your effort in solving the problem.

Using Mathematica: $$\frac{-| x|  \left(\sqrt{-\frac{i \text{$\mu $0}}{\sigma }}+\sqrt{\frac{i \text{$\mu $0}}{\sigma }}\right)-i x \left(\sqrt{-\frac{i \text{$\mu $0}}{\sigma }}-\sqrt{\frac{i
\text{$\mu $0}}{\sigma }}\right)}{4 | x| ^{5/2}}$$.

Thanks, i don't have Mathematica. Is it possible to restrict the calculation for $\omega>0$?

for: $\omega >0$ is: $$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i}{4}\right) (x-| x| ) \sqrt{\frac{i \text{$\mu $0}}{\sigma }}}{| x| ^{5/2}}$$

Thanks, appreciate this.
